# CSS text-shadow not displaying properly on mobile

Tags: ios, css, mobile, shadow

First of all; Hi all! I'm just new in the community. I've been using stack overflow without an account for years since I've always been able to find my answers. This one I can't and it keeps bugging me!

I'm using text-shadow on a h2 element in the header of one my sites. It displays correctly on my desktop (current Chrome, Edge and Firefox versions). On my mobile (iPhone, current Chrome and Safari versions) it results in what you see in the via stack overflow linked image below.

[In this image you'll see 'blocks' with some sort of gradient shade instead of text-shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mz8b.png)

Does anyone have any idea what happens here / seen it before and knows a solution?

Site: http://schuttershoeve.nl

```
CSS:
    .content h2 {
        text-shadow: 0 0 20px #000000;
    }
```

- P.S. you can't reproduce the error now; I've used media queries to remove the shadow from mobile sites as a workaround for now

Comment: did you try adding `-webkit-appearance: none;`  ?

Comment: jess, that doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is Polyfills.

I.e, use CSS text-shadow where supported, and use a css background-image, where unsupported.

See http://modernizr.com/ for detection of support of text-shadow among others.

Tutorial on how to use Modernizr: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/modernizr/

TLDR:

Modernizr will add a CSS class .no-textshadow to your HTML element, if it detects that the browser does not support text-shadows.

Then it's a matter of providing a fallback in your CSS along the lines of .no-textshadow .text-stroke{}

Comment: In the documentation I read that this is for ie 9 and previous browser issues, are the issues in Chrome and Safari IOS related? 

When I check the text-shadow css info and examples on w3 on my mobile I do see the correct shading with the same code.. Shouldn't that mean there is a different issue?

Comment: Could be Maybe just turn the text-shadow to none? In a media querry

Comment: I did this as a workaround as seen in the original post, it's a pity cause it makes the txt a bit less readable on a picture.. ;) Thx for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Ok, it had to do with a box-shadow in combination with the text-shadow. The gradients you see are the box-shadows. I decided to use a non-gradient box-shadow solution on all screen widths to make my text more readable. Thx for the input!